# All modes to combine two arrays

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, function, recursion

I have a dynamic array in this structure:

```
$arr = [
    ['R1', 'R2'],
    ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
    ['M1', 'M2']
];
```

i want to find all combinations for this array i.e:

```
R1A1M1
R1A1M2
R1A2M1
R1A2M2
R1A3M1
R1A3M2
R2A1M1
R2A1M2
R2A2M1
R2A2M2
R2A3M1
R2A3M2
```

because array length is not static we must use a recursive function to solve this problem.
what is code in PHP or js for this problem?

thank you

Comment: and what you've tried yourself ?

Comment: Can you please decide between JavaScript and PHP? Or do you want both solutions?

Comment: I wrote this code for a static array:
https://gist.github.com/smart-twists/b18d23be530f26d6f3007bebc2b0ee89
I prefer to write the function in java script.

Comment: You need to implement a [Power Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var result = [""];
 $arr.forEach(function(arr){
   var tmp = [];
   arr.forEach(function(el){
    result.forEach(function(curr){
     tmp.push(curr+el);
    });
  });
 result = tmp;
});
```

A few iterations should do it...

[Result](http://jsbin.com/qokoyopiba/edit?console)

---

Another, more static approach (probably faster):

```
var result = new Array($arr.reduce((l,a)=>l*a.length,1))
  .fill("");

for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
  var l = result.length / $arr[0].length;
  for(var j = 0; j < $arr.length; j++){
    result[i] += $arr[j][Math.floor(i/l)% $arr[j].length ];
    if($arr[i+1]) l = l / $arr[i+1].length;
  }
```

Comment: this is very very good.
it's awesome.
could you write this code in PHP please?

Comment: No, i dont know php :/

Comment: thank you so much.
I wrote this in PHP :
https://gist.github.com/smart-twists/931358399be55a617ccb674fdc26471d

Answer (score 0):

To get all combinations of your arrays, you need a [Power Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) function

> In mathematics, the power set (or powerset) of any set S, written
>   P(S), ℘(S), P(S), ℙ(S) or 2S, is the set of all subsets of S,
>   including the empty set and S itself.

You could create this yourself, or find such a function pre-written. I will use https://github.com/Xotic750/power-set-x for an example.

```js
const arr = [
  ['R1', 'R2'],
  ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
  ['M1', 'M2']
];

const flattened = [...arr[0], ...arr[1], ...arr[2]];
const combinations = powerSet(flattened);
const stringCombinations = combinations.map(combination => combination.join(''));
console.log(stringCombinations);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Xotic750/power-set-x/master/lib/power-set-x.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var powerSet = returnExports
</script>
```

You can then perform any required filtering or sorting on the results.

For example if you only want the combinations that you have given in your question and in that particular order.

```js
const arr = [
  ['R1', 'R2'],
  ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
  ['M1', 'M2']
];

const flattened = [...arr[0], ...arr[1], ...arr[2]];
const combinations = powerSet(flattened);
const stringCombinations = combinations.map(combination => combination.join(''));
const filtered = stringCombinations.filter(string => /^R\dA\dM\d$/.test(string)).sort();
console.log(filtered);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Xotic750/power-set-x/master/lib/power-set-x.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var powerSet = returnExports
</script>
```

For Power Set functions in many languages, see: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_set

For example, in ES6 Power Set can be written simply as

```js
const arr = [
  ['R1', 'R2'],
  ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
  ['M1', 'M2']
];

const flattened = [...arr[0], ...arr[1], ...arr[2]];
const powerSet = xs => xs.reduceRight((a, x) => a.concat(a.map(y => [x].concat(y))), [[]]);
const combinations = powerSet(flattened);
console.log(combinations);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var mohem = new Array($arr.reduce((l,a)=>l*a.length,1))
  .fill("");

for(var i = 0; i < mohem.length; i++){
  var l = mohem.length / $arr[0].length;
  for(var j = 0; j < $arr.length; j++){
    mohem[i] += $arr[j][Math.floor(i/l)% $arr[j].length ];
    if($arr[i+1]) l = l / $arr[i+1].length;
  }
```

Comment: thank you.
your answer is similar to previus answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single line approach with ES6

```js
var array = [['R1', 'R2'], ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'], ['M1', 'M2']],
    result = array.reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []));

console.log(result.map(a => a.join('')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows;

```js
var arr = [ ['R1', 'R2'], ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'], ['M1', 'M2']];
    res = arr.reduceRight((a,b) => b.reduce((r,e) => r.concat(a.map(f => e + f)), []));
console.log(res);
```